# Developer downloading ledger reasoning?

Tags: web3js, infura, ethernodes

My question is a little odd, but I will ask it anyways.

From a development perspective, knowing that there is a service such as Infura, why would a developer download the whole ledger? Infura provides a ready ethereum node that will allow the dev to interact with.

Is there value from operating the node yourself? I know having a personal node means being in full control of the node but can you elaborate? Please provide examples I'm just starting out with ethereum.

from another question [linked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/what-are-the-valuable-benefits-of-having-a-node)

> It means that one direct benefit for you is that you won't have problem with overloaded tier nodes that would prevent you from including your transactions on the network. You'll still have problem including your transaction to a block as mining nodes may include transactions with higher fees first, but at least you will skip the first obstacle.

Getting your transactions in the network faster, this is definitely a benefit for the developer. Are there others?

Comment: It only answers it partially as it takes on the benefit from a user of the ethereum network. The portion from the list is as follow : "It means that one direct benefit for you is that you won't have problem with overloaded tier nodes that would prevent you from including your transactions on the network. You'll still have problem including your transaction to a block as mining nodes may include transactions with higher fees first, but at least you will skip the first obstacle." However, it doesn't take on more details such as speed of development and workload on the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Strongest benefit for using your own node is that you don't rely on 3rd party service for example Infura. If infura go down then your application cannot write on the blockchain. Also while running your own node you can setup different parameters for example how many peers you want to connect with or which accounts you want to unlock on node starting so you don't have to sign the transactions everytime in the code.