# What are the Benefits of running an Ethereum Full Node if you are not mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets, mainnet, full-node

As stated in the title, what is the direct or indirect benefit i stand to gain from running a full node on the Ethereum mainnet or Testnet

I know Nicholas has a brilliant answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4111/55269), but it's about 5 years old and there have been significant changes in the protocol ( some of which Nicholas even foresaw and talked about in his 2016 answer )

so, with the latest changes (as of December 2021) being considered, as a non-miner what benefitd do stand to i gain by running an Ethereum Full Node ?

Answer (score 1):

My main argument would be something that Vitalik himself mentioned somewhere, which Nicholas answer didn't entirely touch upon:

If everyone relies on the same third party node provider, then they hold the power to silently upgrade the entire network (say, adding a 10x boost for miners). Since everyone is relying on those few node providers, they won't have any chance, but to accept the upgrade by default. Running your own node would mitigate this risk, since you are relying on your own underlying code and not someone else's which could be changed. In that way, you are also contributing to ethereum's security.